# iOS GET Twitter & Parse.com - Authorisation Method

Tags: xcode, twitter, oauth, parse-platform

I am developing an app for iOS. The app is to store the tweetIDs of the tweets the user has made which include another twitter handle in.

I can successfully log a user into a twitter account on the device through the Social Framework and call the API to receive and page through past tweets. However this takes up a lot of bandwidth on the device & I would prefer for the server (Parse.com) to do this for me, as it is here where the IDs will be stored. Is the social framework enough for this or do I need to create a Oauth from scratch for Java SDK for coding the parse server?

Thanks

D

Answer (score -1):

```
NSString * requestString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json?screen_name=%@", user.username];


            NSURL *verify = [NSURL URLWithString:requestString];
            NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:verify];
            [[PFTwitterUtils twitter] signRequest:request];
            NSURLResponse *response = nil;
            NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                                                 returningResponse:&response
                                                             error:&error];
```

You pass in the username of the user you want to authenticate for. Then create an NSDictionary object and use the `'NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:options:` method with the NSData `data` object that you get from the request to be able to use the results of the response. Happy coding.

Comment: But won't this code send the data to the ios device? I want it to be received by the parse server directly?